# Convergence in distribution by taking Taylor expansion

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am looking into a proof of high dimensional multi-variance matrix. But I didn't get it how the statistic T_n converge to N(0,2)

[image: Link to the question's screenshot]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community There is a sentence from the text claiming $\sqrt{n/p} T_n \overset{d}{\to} N(0,2)$ without justification beyond "take a Taylor expansion," and OP is asking for more details about how to prove this claim.